# How to fire one function for two separate events in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 events, a keydown and a click. I would like to put them into a single function and when the function is called, whichever event was fired would do what it's supposed to.

Example:

```
var close = function () {
    $('.alert').remove();
};

$(document).on('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        //27 = ESC
        close();
    }
});

$('.alertBG').on('click', function () {
    close();
});
```

I can't think of a way to get the `document` and `.alertBG` parts to play nicely. ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L0ejnwxd/4/))

Comment: What do you mean by "play nicely"?

Comment: You can't combine them into one.

Comment: You have to add two event listeners, but you can use one function to do the actual result. As you do there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't. Your functions are too different. You have already factored the reusable parts of them out into a `close` function that you call from both. This is the best way to do it.

---

If you really wanted to, then you would have to bind a click/keydown handler to `document` and test the type of event and the element.

```
$(document).on("keydown click", function (event) {
    if (
    (event.type === "keydown" && event.keyCode === 27) || (event.type === "click" && (
    $(event.target).is(".alertBG") || $(event.target).parents(".alertBG").length))) {
        close();
    }
});
```

As you can see, it's much cleaner just to bind your event handlers separately when there are so many differences between them.

Comment: That looks really hefty (and confusing). Just knowing that it can be done is good enough for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
function handler(event) {
    if(event.type === "click") {
        close();
    } else if(event.type === "keydown") {
        if (event.keyCode === 27) {
            //27 = ESC
            close();
        }
    }
}

$(document).on('keydown', handler);
$('.alertBG').on('click', handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything like this ?

```
function myFunc(method){
    if(method == "one"){
       // do anything
    }
    else if(method == "other"){
       // do other thing
    }
}

$(document).on('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
       myFunc("one");
    }
});

$('.alertBG').on('click', function () {
    myFunc("other");
});
```